# Increase airflow central air

Tags: air-conditioning

I have central air in my home and the majority of the house gets really cold with no problem.  However, my master bedroom has a washer/dryer & I typically use my laptop for leisure.

With that being said, the room gets quite warm.  I can have the A/C in the home set for 65 and while the downstairs is cold, the bedroom is not.  I have horizontal windows so buying an additional A/C would be a pain.

Would I be better off purchasing a stand-up fan such as the Dyson? Or should I be looking to do something else?

Comment: Have you tried closing some of the registers in other rooms, to force the cool air to be redirected more to the bedroom?  Be careful not to close too many registers.

Comment: I tried closing a lot of the registers, I can try opening a few to see if that's the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you really need to nail down why that room is warmer than the other rooms as I doubt you're doing laundry all day every day.

Is the room on the south side of the house?

Does it have more windows than other rooms?

Are the windows properly insulated and caulked and not leaking air?

Is there poor air circulation in the attic above that room for some reason? Do you have an exhaust fan in your attic with proper soffit vents or other intake vents?

Are the plumbing and exhaust vents for the w/d properly sealed? Is the dryer vent in an insulated wall?

Is there sufficient insulation in the walls and attic in that room?

Are the amount and size of AC registers in the room appropriate for the room?

After addressing any existing problems with air or heat leaking you may want to consider a couple of different options.

If the hallway outside the bedroom is cooler you might want to create a vent to allow air to pass through from your bedroom and hallway.

Probably the better option is to have someone install another register off the main duct so you have more cool are entering the room provided your system can handle it.